# How to convert this VBA to a ready-to-use add ins?

Tags: vba, excel

I want to convert the following VBA to an add-ins in excel. It basically uses a table in sheet 2 to modify the content of sheet1. The table has two columns, one for the "word to be replaced" and the other one is for the word to be "replaced by".

This is to be used by users who are unfamiliar with programming this is why I need it as a ready icon on excel.
Code:

```
Sub Substitutions()

    Dim rngData     As Range
    Dim rngLookup   As Range
    Dim Lookup      As Range

    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        Set rngData = .Range("A1", .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    End With

    With Sheets("Sheet2")
        Set rngLookup = .Range("A1", .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    End With

    For Each Lookup In rngLookup
        If Lookup.Value <> "" Then
            rngData.Replace What:=Lookup.Value, _
                            Replacement:=Lookup.Offset(0, 1).Value, _
                            LookAt:=xlPart, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                            MatchCase:=False
        End If
    Next Lookup

End Sub
```

Comment: Did you try saving as an add-in? I'm not sure your code will work as-is, since it refers always to the active workbook (since you don't explicitly use ThisWorkBook) Do your workbooks all have a "Sheet2" with the mapping table, or is that intended to live in your add-in?

Comment: @TimWilliams I'm really a begginer so I'm not sure if it will work as an add-ins too. Yes whenever I want to use this add ins the table in sheet 2 will be available. Can you please guide me how to make it work by mentioning "ThisWorkBook".. I really have no clue. Thanks!

Comment: Use `ThisWorkbook` when you want to refer to the workbook containing the VBA code: use `ActiveWorkbook` when you want to refer to the currently active workbook (your code defaults to this if nothing else is specified).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you have fixed your code to work with proper workbook and worksheets, you need to change the **IsAddin** propety of the `ThisWorkbook`. Then Save from the VBE to a .xlam file. You should sign the macro and make others to trust your self-signed digital certificate, then add the Addin manually on their computer. You should also add a button in a ribbon too, otherwise you can't tell if your Addin is enabled or not.

[image: IsAddin]
[image: SaveAsXLAM]